# Подключение System.net, System.IO

Tags: .net, delphi, delphi-xe2

При подключении в Delphi XE2 к проекту `uses System.Net, System.IO` выдаёт ошибки:

> [DCC Fatal Error] Update.pas(7): F1026 File not found: 'System.Net.dcu' (unit scope "System" indicates Win64, OSX32, Win32 only).
>
> [DCC Fatal Error] Update.pas(7): F1026 File not found: 'System.IO.dcu' (unit scope "System" indicates Win64, OSX32, Win32 only).

Компонент 4 версии в системе присутствует, почему выдаёт ошибку?
При печати `System.` среда предлагает список элементов в котором нету `.Net .IO`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работаю с примером на C#, возможно ли подключение этих библиотек в Delphi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если только вы не используете Delphi for .NET или Delphi Prism (а вы, очевидно, используете не её), вы не должны и не можете использовать рантайм .Net.

У Delphi своя стандартная библиотека, свой рантайм, свои модули, все свое.

Delphi никак не связан с C#.